# Running the basic Google App

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to run the basic google app in my localhost. But I seem to have some error which i am not able to solve:

Error when i typed: dev_appserver.py /Users/GoogleApp/helloworld

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 694, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 582, in main
    root_path, {}, default_partition=default_partition)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3217, in LoadAppConfig
    raise AppConfigNotFoundError
google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError
```

Not able to solve it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo need to have an app.yaml file in you application directory (in your case /Users/GoogleApp/helloworld). See [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig) for details. Refer to the [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) (section Creating the Configuration File) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `helloworld` subdirectory outside the sdk directory, eg:

```
/home/helloworld
```